# My 2000 VW Beetle won't accelerate but the RPM skyrockets?

Tags: vw, beetle

I just purchased a 2000 Volkswagon Beetle and it was by all accounts a good deal. Everything seemed in order, I even had my mechanic look it over before I purchased it. It' s been a few days and now all the sudden when I push on the gas, even if it's lightly, the RPM will shoot up and the car will sound like I slammed on the gas, but won't actually speed up.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Automatic transmission or standard? If the latter, suspect the clutch or related mechanism. If the former, check the fluid level as per the manual.

Comment: Have to agree with @fred_dot_u here.